# C++ While Loop Will Not Repeat

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the WHILE loop in my program to repeat. I have been at this for about 4 hours now so maybe I am just missing something.

I am not able to get the loop to reiterate no matter what I type in. Furthermore, if I type in more than one character in the prompt, then it skips all 7 of my subsequent loops.

Then, even better, the variables at the end don't even change when something is typed in, hopefully you can help me with all of the problems listed above (the simpler the better). But I would take just one at this point.

```
    cout << "Welcome. Input anything to start the sales reporting process.\n\n";
cin >> start; **//If I enter more than one character here it skips my other loops**
if (start == start)
{
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter the amount of each sale for Darwin when prompted, only enter one at a time.\n";
    cout << "When you are finished entering sales, input a '1'.\n\n";
    cout << "Enter a sale for Darwin: ";
    cin >> darwinSale;
    cout << endl << endl;
    while(darwinSale =! 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a sale for Darwin: ";
        cin >> darwinSale;
        if (darwinSale <= 50999)
            darwinCom = darwinSale * 0.04;
        if (darwinSale >= 51000 and darwinSale <= 125999)
            darwinCom = darwinSale * 0.05;
        if (darwinSale >= 126000 and darwinSale <= 200999)
            darwinCom = darwinSale * 0.06;
        if (darwinSale >= 201000)
            darwinCom = darwinSale * 0.07;
        darwinComTotal = darwinComTotal + darwinCom;
        darwinTotal = darwinSale + darwinTotal;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
```

Comment: try changing it to while(darwinSale != 1)

Comment: Ah, yes, the dreaded `=!` operator. Change it to `!=`. As written, in `darwinSale =! 1`, the `!` applies to the `1`, and the result (`0`) gets assigned to `darwinSale` producing a value of 0 and immediately terminating the loop.

Comment: Also your if statement is redundant, start == start should always equal true as it is comparing against itself.

Answer (score 8):

In your while condition, you are actually checking:

```
while(drawinSale = !1)
```

And !1 checks if 1 == NULL wich returns 0

You should instead do the following:

```
while(drawinSale != 1)
```

Comment: There's no NULL checking – `1` is converted to `true`, which is then negated to `false`, which is converted to `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I owe you my sanity, sir.